# Compare 2 dates from strings,char* or int

Tags: c++, string

i have a problem here, i have been trying to compare a date format from `SYSTEMTIME` and a date from a text file(`string`).But its not working. I tried to change both to string(using `osstringstream`),`char*` and int(using `sscanf`) to do the comparison but with no luck. its pretty simple all i want to do is get the current system date and compare it with the date from the text file. Below is my code:

```
char szcurrentDate[MAX_PATH] = "";
char szdate_time[MAX_PATH];
SYSTEMTIME st;
GetLocalTime(&st);
GetDateFormat(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, NULL, &st, "yyyy-M-d ", szcurrentDate,
              MAX_PATH);  // current system date
// std::ostringstream mm;
// stringstream mm;
// mm << szcurrentDate;
MessageBoxA(NULL, szcurrentDate, "Attention", IDOK == IDCANCEL);
ifstream ifs(szFile);
string line;
while (!ifs.eof())
{
    getline(ifs, line);
    if ((line.find("TESTING_GET_DATE:") != string::npos))
    {
        std::string str = line.substr(
            17, 9);  // substract TESTING_GET_DATE: 2014-3-16 to  2014-3-16
        strcpy(szdate_time, str.c_str());
        if (szcurrentDate == szdate_time)
        {
            MessageBoxA(NULL, "Same", "Attention", MB_OK);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBoxA(NULL, "blablabla", "Attention", MB_OK);
        }
```

note : i tried displaying just `szcurrentDate` and `szdate_time` they show the date exactly the same. in `string`,`char*` or `int` formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
strcpy(szdate_time, str.c_str());
if (szcurrentDate == szdate_time)
```

Makes no sense.  You are copying a C++ string to a C string (unnecessarily), then comparing the pointers to the two char arrays (which will never be equal, as the contents are not compared, only the addresses).

You could fix it like this:

```
if (szcurrentDate == str)
```

That will invoke `operator==` for std::string, which does compare the string contents.  And it's less code.

Comment: thanks John,it does invoke the == operator but how do i do the compare both the contents of the date?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking now.

Comment: i mean how do you use (szcurrentDate == str) to compare the dates from   szcurrentDate and szdate_time..sorry im a little slow today.

Comment: sorry John, i got what you meant, and somehow the compare does not work, i get "blablabla" as the message..

Comment: So print the two dates and see how they differ.

Comment: thats the thing,before posting the question i tried printing them out using the MessageBox and both of the dates are identical..

Comment: If they are identical and you are comparing `std::string`s rather than C strings, the comparison should evaluate to true.  You seem to have a trailing space in your format though, so probably the difference is just that whitespace.

Comment: oh my god, you are absolutely correct and i have been checking my text file codes for white spaces and did not realize my SYSTEMFILE  format has a white space "yyyy-M-d " changed it to "yyyy-M-d" and it worked. Thanks alot John! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare character arrays by using ==.  That works for string objects, but not C style strings.  You need to use strcmp() on them, of you need to use string objects for the dates.

Comment: hi Gabe, yes i tried using strcmp by doing this : 
std::string str1 = szcurrentDate;  
std::string str2 = szdate_time;
strcmp(szcurrentDate,szdate_time)==0)
but does not work, i converted them to string and compared.